# What's the higher-performance alternative to for-loops for subsetting data by group-id?

Tags: r, performance, loops, data.table, subset

A recurring analysis paradigm I encounter in my research is the need to subset based on all different group id values, performing statistical analysis on each group in turn, and putting the results in an output matrix for further processing/summarizing.

How I typically do this in R is something like the following:

```
data.mat <- read.csv("...")  
groupids <- unique(data.mat$ID)  #Assume there are then 100 unique groups
  
results <- matrix(rep("NA",300),ncol=3,nrow=100)  

for(i in 1:100) {  
  tempmat <- subset(data.mat,ID==groupids[i])  

  # Run various stats on tempmat (correlations, regressions, etc), checking to  
  # make sure this specific group doesn't have NAs in the variables I'm using  
  # and assign results to x, y, and z, for example.  

  results[i,1] <- x  
  results[i,2] <- y  
  results[i,3] <- z  
}
```

This ends up working for me, but depending on the size of the data and the number of groups I'm working with, this can take up to three days.

Besides branching out into parallel processing, is there any "trick" for making something like this run faster? For instance, converting the loops into something else (something like an `apply` with a function containing the stats I want to run inside the loop), or eliminating the need to actually assign the subset of data to a variable?

#### Edit:

Maybe this is just common knowledge (or sampling error), but I tried subsetting with brackets in some of my code rather than using the subset command, and it seemed to provide a slight performance gain which surprised me. I have some code I used and output below using the same object names as above:

```
system.time(for(i in 1:1000){data.mat[data.mat$ID==groupids[i],]})
```

> ```
>    user  system elapsed  
>  361.41   92.62  458.32
> ```

```
system.time(for(i in 1:1000){subset(data.mat,ID==groupids[i])})
```

> ```
>    user  system elapsed   
>  378.44  102.03  485.94
> ```

#### Update:

In one of the answers, jorgusch suggested that I use the `data.table` package to speed up my subsetting. So, I applied it to a problem I ran earlier this week. In a dataset with a little over 1,500,000 rows, and 4 columns (ID,Var1,Var2,Var3), I wanted to calculate two correlations in each group (indexed by the "ID" variable). There are slightly more than 50,000 groups. Below is my initial code (which is very similar to the above):

```
data.mat <- read.csv("//home....")  
groupids <- unique(data.mat$ID)
  
results <- matrix(rep("NA",(length(groupids) * 3)),ncol=3,nrow=length(groupids))  

for(i in 1:length(groupids)) {  
  tempmat <- data.mat[data.mat$ID==groupids[i],] 

  results[i,1] <- groupids[i]  
  results[i,2] <- cor(tempmat$Var1,tempmat$Var2,use="pairwise.complete.obs")  
  results[i,3] <- cor(tempmat$Var1,tempmat$Var3,use="pairwise.complete.obs")    

}
```

I'm re-running that right now for an exact measure of how long that took, but from what I remember, I started it running when I got into the office in the morning and it finished sometime in the mid-afternoon. Figure 5-7 hours.

Restructuring my code to use data.table....

```
data.mat <- read.csv("//home....")  
data.mat <- data.table(data.mat)  
  
testfunc <- function(x,y,z) {  
  temp1 <- cor(x,y,use="pairwise.complete.obs")  
  temp2 <- cor(x,z,use="pairwise.complete.obs")  
  res <- list(temp1,temp2)  
  res  
}  

system.time(test <- data.mat[,testfunc(Var1,Var2,Var3),by="ID"])
```

> ```
>  user  system  elapsed  
> 16.41    0.05    17.44
> ```

Comparing the results using data.table to the ones I got from using a for loop to subset all IDs and record results manually, they seem to have given me the same answers(though I'll have to check that a bit more thoroughly). That looks to be a pretty big speed increase.

#### Update 2:

Running the code using subsets finally finished up again:

> ```
>    user     system   elapsed  
> 17575.79  4247.41   23477.00
> ```

#### Update 3:

I wanted to see if anything worked out differently using the plyr package that was also recommended. This is my first time using it, so I may have done things somewhat inefficiently, but it still helped substantially compared to the for loop with subsetting.

Using the same variables and setup as before...

```
data.mat <- read.csv("//home....")  
system.time(hmm <- ddply(data.mat,"ID",function(df)c(cor(df$Var1,df$Var2,  use="pairwise.complete.obs"),cor(df$Var1,df$Var3,use="pairwise.complete.obs"))))
```

> ```
>   user  system elapsed  
> 250.25    7.35  272.09
> ```

Comment: So each group has about three observations? That's not many to be calculating a correlation from.

Comment: The group sizes range from 1 to around 300. We're working within a quasi meta-analytic framework to use maximum information, sample-size weighting every correlation so the groups with small numbers of people don't get weighted very much.

Comment: Whoops, I counted zeroes wrong when I wrote the number of rows. It's a little over 1,500,000, rather than 150,000

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty much exactly what the `plyr` package is designed to make easier.  However it's unlikely that it will make things much faster - most of the time is probably spent doing the statistics.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That was my impression from skimming through the manual for the plyr package awhile back; that it generally made things simpler to write, but wouldn't provide much in the performance realm. I'd probably use plyr, but I'm in a workgroup where most aren't very experienced with R and the for loop along with the explicitness of what's happening inside seems to be pretty intuitive to read. Maybe I'll give plyr a try though and see if it provides any benefits. Every little bit helps :)

Comment: Also, according to some code I wrote in the above format that I used Rprof on, the vast majority of time spent in the above code is spent on subsetting the dataset.

Comment: Exactly how big is `data.mat`?

Comment: Talking of speed, data.table is much faster - see answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Besides `plyr`, you can try to use [`foreach`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) package to exclude explicit loop counter, but I don't know if it will give you any performance benefits.

`Foreach`, neverless, gives you a quite simple interface to parallel chunk processing if you have multicore workstation (with `doMC`/`multicore` packages) (check [Getting Started with doMC and foreach](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/vignettes/gettingstartedMC.pdf) for details), if you exclude parallel processing only because it is not very easy to understand for students. If it is not the only reason, `plyr` is very good solution IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

You have already suggested vectorizing and avoiding making unnecessary copies of intermediate results, so you are certainly on the right track. Let me caution you not to do what i did and just *assume* that vectorizing will *always* give you a performance boost (like it does in other languages, e.g., Python + NumPy, MATLAB).

An example:

```
# small function to time the results:
time_this = function(...) {
  start.time = Sys.time(); eval(..., sys.frame(sys.parent(sys.parent()))); 
  end.time = Sys.time(); print(end.time - start.time)
}

# data for testing: a 10000 x 1000 matrix of random doubles
a = matrix(rnorm(1e7, mean=5, sd=2), nrow=10000)

# two versions doing the same thing: calculating the mean for each row
# in the matrix
x = time_this( for (i in 1:nrow(a)){ mean( a[i,] ) } )
y = time_this( apply(X=a, MARGIN=1, FUN=mean) )

print(x)    # returns => 0.5312099
print(y)    # returns => 0.661242
```

The 'apply' version is actually **slower** than the 'for' version. (According to the *Inferno* author, if you are doing this you are not vectorizing, you are 'loop hiding'.)

But where you can get a performance boost is by using **built-ins**.  Below, i've timed the same operation as the two above, just using the built-in function, 'rowMeans':

```
z = time_this(rowMeans(a))
print(z)    # returns => 0.03679609
```

An order of magnitude improvement versus the 'for' loop (and the vectorized version).

The other members of the apply family are not just wrappers over a native 'for' loop.

```
a = abs(floor(10*rnorm(1e6)))

time_this(sapply(a, sqrt))
# returns => 6.64 secs

time_this(for (i in 1:length(a)){ sqrt(a[i])})
# returns => 1.33 secs
```

'sapply' is about **5x** slower compared with a 'for' loop.

Finally, w/r/t vectorized versus 'for' loops, i don't think i ever use a loop if i can use a vectorized function--the latter is usually less keystrokes and and it's a more natural way (for me) to code, which is a different kind of performance boost, i suppose.

Comment: Using apply is not vectorizing.

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstood, but don't the results show that using sapply gives a 5x performance decrement rather than a boost? That's how it turned out when I ran your code fragments. In any case, thank you for the detailed example of applys not always helping out. I don't think I have to worry about that in this case though, as unless I'm mistaken, the apply family doesn't apply (ha!) to the situation where you're subsetting chunks of the dataset and performing some sort of statistical operation on that chunk because it's not going down the vector and doing the same thing on all items/rows

Comment: Doug, why the `time_this()` business when there is `system.time()`? And why not several reruns?  I often do something like 'mean(replicate(N, system.time(someRexpressionHere)["elapsed"]), trim=0.1)' which drops the best and worst times and averages over the remainder. One could argue for summary() or median() or ... but the point is: one data point, as you show here, is not that informative as you may get hit by function loading times etc which are really one-offs.

Comment: In your (s)apply / for comparisons you don't save the data within the timing function for the for... unfair.  Do that and things even out or favour apply family.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find plyr not very easy to understand. I prefer data.table which is also faster. For instance you want to do the standard deviation of colum my_column for each ID.

```
dt <- datab.table[df] # one time operation...changing format of df to table
result.sd <- dt[,sd(my_column),by="ID"] # result with each ID and SD in second column
```

Three statements of this kind and a cbind at the end - that is all you need.
You can also use dt do some action for only one ID without a subset command in an new syntax:

```
result.sd.oneiD<- dt[ID="oneID",sd(my_column)]
```

The first statment refers to rows (i), the second to columns (j).

If find it easier to read then player and it is more flexible, as you can also do sub domains within a "subset"...
The documentation describes that it uses SQL-like methods. For instance, the by is pretty much "group by" in SQL. Well, if you know SQL, you can probably do much more, but it is not necessary to make use of the package.
Finally, it is extremely fast, as each operation is not only parallel, but also data.table grabs the data needed for calculation. Subset, however, maintain the levels of the whole matrix and drag it trough the memory.